# Missing text in IE11

Tags: browser-compatibility

This may not be specific to WordPress, but I'm developing a WP site and have come across a puzzling problem. My client has some computers at the office running IE11 and he's noticing missing bits of text. Near as I can tell it's around type that has phone numbers and dollar signs.

The site is here: oasisorcutt.org

I can see the problems if I go to browerstack and use the emulate IE11 mode.

For instance, in the footer, all the text in the "Contact" widget doesn't show up. If you go to Activities >> Groups & Activities and scroll down to "Reflexology" you can see that the end of the sentence is missing (compare with Chrome or Firefox).

Another example: Go to "Resources" and scroll down a little to "Center for Successful Aging" -- right below the headline you will see a web address and phone number if you are viewing in Chrome or Firefox, but the whole line is missing in IE11.

If I switch this site to IE "compatibility mode" the missing text shows up -- but "compatibility mode" creates all kinds of other weird and worse problems.

Anybody have any idea what's going on here and, more importantly, how to solve this?

Comment: you know it is off-topic, so why do you ask? you just wasted your time and the time of the moderators which will see it in their "close" queue.

Comment: Sorry. I just hope it can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the issue: I'm using the Bourbon Neat sass library and it adds a line: `@include font-feature-settings("kern", "liga", "pnum");` that IE apparently doesn't like. I removed this mixin include and the IE problem went away.